# Displaying Blob from App Engine Datastore as an image

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an App Engine Connected Android Project, so I am using endpoints. I ultimately converted the bitmap from my Android project into an encoded string to use in my setter, where I converted this string back into a byte array and then to a Blob, and then persisted the blob to the datastore. I know when to retrieve this Blob and display it as the actual image on the app engine front end. How can I do this? I'm a very beginner, especially with using Blobs.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/).

> If you are serving images, a more efficient and potentially
>   less-expensive method is to use getServingUrl() using the App Engine
>   Images API rather than blobstoreService.serve(). The getServingUrl
>   method lets you serve the image directly, without having to go through
>   your App Engine instances.

So basically having a blobkey you can use

```
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
                .withBlobKey(blobKey);
        String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
```

And access that image as "static" content hosted by Google without going through your server.